# Bootstrap design query

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a questions display page for a survey.

And I have a collection of questions in a loop,

If the questions count is odd, First question should come in one row (col-12) and all other questions should be two per row (col-6, col-6)

If the questions count is even, All questions should be two per row (col-6, col-6)

How can I do this in Bootstrap the design should be dynamic inside the loop.

[image]

I tried some options inside the loop but could not get o work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the class of all the elements to col-6 by default, and set the first element to a set ID aswell.
Using JS, it is possible to :

```
If (odd) {
   document.getElementById("first_element_id").classList.remove("col-6")
   document.getElementById("first_element_id").classList.add("col-12")
}
```

This above can be put into a loop. Of course, a reverse function of this (adding col-6 and removing col-12) will be have to put in-place incase the count is even.